# Couchbase Lite (Mobile) local database API for Cordova/Ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, couchbase, cordova-plugins, couchbase-lite

I was wondering if there is any Couchbase Lite Cordova plugin or API to just access and use the database locally on any android/ios mobile device?

I was trying to search in the official documentation. It didn't help!

Comment: Have you tried [Couchbase-Lite-PhoneGap-Plugin](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Couchbase-Lite-PhoneGap-Plugin)?

Comment: Do you know any good examples of using the above plugin? There is no clear usage of how do we access the database and store content into it and retrieve it. I even saw this [CouchChat Example](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/CouchChat-PhoneGap). It was way to complex for me to understand and it didn't show how to access the device local database.

Comment: Please see this [TODO sample](http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2014/12/11/up-and-running-with-couchbase-lite-phonegap/)

Comment: Have you seen Couchbase page: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/get-started/get-started-mobile/phonegap/build-and-run/index.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [couchbase-lite-phonegap-plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/couchbase-lite/) is an official ionic plugin for iOS and Android. You can install it in ionic v2+ with:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add couchbase-lite-phonegap-plugin
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/couchbase-lite
```

You won't be able to access [Couchbase Lite Native API](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.4/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/index.html), which includes N1QL for example, but you can operate local databases with [Couchbase Lite REST API](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.4/references/couchbase-lite/rest-api/index.html).

This plugin basically just gives you an URL to make requests to your local CBLite, allowing you to manage local databases, their documents and views (design docs with JavaScript functions), etc. And you can also start and cancel  push and pull replications with Sync Gateway, each one a continuous or a one-time operation. The replications run in background unassisted, but you can monitor them with the _active_tasks method and get notified of local database changes with the _changes method.

However, for ease of usage, when developing a full featured mobile app, you'll need a wrapper to encapsulate those HTTP REST requests. You'll find some examples in [CouchbaseLabs](https://github.com/couchbaselabs) repo.